# Delete layers of keras pretrained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use vgg16 pre-trained model of keras. I have notice some strange behavior when trying to change the model.

1) I have add some `layers` of the per-trained model. My problem is that tensorboard is showing the layers of the model that I didn't add into the sequence model. This is strange because I have also deleted the imported model. I think this have to do with the dependency between layers so I want to remove this dependencies.  How can I do this?

[image]

For example in this picture there is two layers that I didn't add but they are showing in the graph

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()


cnnModel = keras.models.Sequential()

for layer in vgg16_model.layers[0:13]:
    cnnModel.add(layer)

for layer in vgg16_model.layers[14:16]:
    cnnModel.add(layer)

for layer in vgg16_model.layers[17:21]:
    cnnModel.add(layer)

cnnModel.add(keras.layers.Dense(2048, name="compress_1"))
cnnModel.add(keras.layers.Dense(1024, name="compress_2"))
cnnModel.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, name="compress_3"))


for layer in cnnModel.layers[0:4]:
    layer.trainable = False

del vgg16_model
```

2) the second problem occurs when using `cnnModel.pop()`. In fact I have add all the layers but I do a pop to the layer I don't want before adding the next one this is the error I get.

```
Layer block4_conv2 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the notion of "layer output" is ill-defined. Use `get_output_at(node_index)` instead.
```

And this is the code I am using:

```
for layer in vgg16_model.layers[0:14]:
    cnnModel.add(layer)

cnnModel.pop()

for layer in vgg16_model.layers[14:17]:
    cnnModel.add(layer)

cnnModel.pop()

for layer in vgg16_model.layers[17:21]:
    cnnModel.add(layer)
```

`cnnModel.pop()` is working the problem only occurs when trying to add the next layer.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you solve it? i'm facing the same case

Comment: I also have the same issue. But funny thing is that, when I plot the model the discarded layers don't show up although TensorBoard still shows them. Use `from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model` `plot_model(model, to_file = 'model_plot.png', show_shapes = True, show_layer_names = True)` to plot the model and see. My only concern is that, I don't want the unnecessary layers increase the computational cost.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `Model` instead of `Sequential`, like:

```
vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()

drop_layers = [13, 16]

input_layer = x = vgg16_model.input

for i, layer in enumerate(vgg16_model.layers[1:], 1):
    if i not in drop_layers:
        x = layer(x)

x = keras.layers.Dense(2048, name="compress_1")(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(1024, name="compress_2")(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(512, name="compress_3")(x)

cnnModel = keras.models.Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = x)

for layer in cnnModel.layers[0:4]:
    layer.trainable = False

del vgg16_model
```

Comment: it didn't work. I still have the parallel layer I don't think `del vgg16_model` is working.

Comment: And if you do `cnnModel.summary()` what do you see it?

Comment: I see the correct layers. it cannot show me the parallel layer because they are related to vgg16_model. I have also tried `del layer` in the loop for the two layer that I should drop but this is not working

Comment: Thank you .. Model instead of Sequential can solve Layer block4_conv2 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the notion of "layer output" is ill-defined. Use `get_output_at(node_index)` instead.

Comment: Does this work if one of the layers requires multiple inputs?